# 'AsyncEnumerableReader' reached the configured maximum size, but not using AsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 3.1.1 (dotnet core 3.1.1). And I want to return a large number of Car entities. Unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
'AsyncEnumerableReader' reached the configured maximum size of the buffer when enumerating a value of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`...
```

I know that there is another answered question regarding the same error. But I'm not doing an explicit async operation.

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(Car[]))]
public IActionResult Index()
{
   return Ok(_carsDataModelContext.Cars.AsEnumerable());
}
```

The _carDataModelContext.Car is just a simple entity that maps 1-on-1 to a table in the database. `public virtual DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }`

Originally I return `Ok(_carsDataModelContext.Cars.AsQueryable())` because we need to support OData. But to be sure it wasn't OData that is messing things up I tried to return AsEnumerable, and remove the "[EnableQuery]" attribute from the method. But that still ends in the same error.

The only way to fix this, is if I return `Ok(_carsDataModelContext.Cars.ToList())`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986882/asyncenumerablereader-reached-the-configured-maximum-size-of-the-buffer-when-e

Comment: @IanKemp the "I know that there is another answered question regarding the same error. But I'm not doing an explicit async operation" is regarding the exact question you're linking. I'm not doing an explicit async operation.

Comment: @Saab what does that mean? What did you try, what was the error, how big is `Car`? And what do you expect `AsEnumerable()` to do? It still has to load *everything* into memory before it can be returned to the client.

Comment: @Saab that duplicate actually explains what the problem is, and how to fix it. There's a limit on how much RAM a single request or response can use, to prevent bad requests from bringing down the server. ActionResult methods that *don't* accept a Stream will read and serialize everything before generating the response. They have to, to calculate a proper `Content-Length` value. The alternative is to create a custom `ActionResult` that holds the `IEnumerable` and writes *directly* to the response stream

Comment: This is already answered in [Streaming large list of data as JSON format using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269438/streaming-large-list-of-data-as-json-format-using-json-net). The accepted answer shows how to create a `JsonStreamingResult` that writes the contents of an `IEnumerable` directly to the Response stream, as an array. The *client* will still have to receive everything before parsing the array though

Comment: An alternative is to create an ASP.NET Core gRPC or SignalR service, and *stream* individual records to the client. The client will have to be modified to use gRPC or SignalR though. This provides true streaming and async operations

Comment: The article [Use streaming in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-3.1) explains how to use SignalR for streaming. Steve Gordon's [Server Streaming with gRPC in ASP.NET Core](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/server-streaming-with-grpc-in-asp-dotnet-core) shows how easy it is to create a gRPC endpoint. Also check [the docs and tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This used to work perfectly fine in .NET Core 2.1 & 2.2. And the "duplicate" states that there is a limit on and IAsyncEnumerable which I don't use. The Action is also not an async method. On of the solutions is "Don't use IAsyncEnumerable".

When I do a ToList() it works just fine. So it has nothing to do with the JSON Serialization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All Ef Core `IQueryable<T>` implementations (`DbSet<T>`, `EntityQueryable<T>`) also implement the standard `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` interface (when used from .NET Core 3), so `AsEnumerable()`, `AsQueryable()` and `AsAsyncEnumerable()` simply return the *same* instance cast to the corresponding interface.

You can easily verify that with the following snippet:

```
var queryable = _carsDataModelContext.Cars.AsQueryable();
var enumerable = queryable.AsEnumerable();
var asyncEnumerable = queryable.AsAsyncEnumerable();
Debug.Assert(queryable == enumerable && queryable == asyncEnumerable);
```

So even though you are not returning explicitly `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, the underlying object implements it and can be queried for. Knowing that Asp.Net Core is naturally async framework, we can safely assume that it checks if the object implements the new standard `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, and uses that behind the scenes instead of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Of course when you use `ToList()`, the returned `List<T>` class does not implement `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, hence the only option is to use `IEnumerable<T>`.

This should explain the 3.1 behavior. Note that before 3.0 there was no standard `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` interface. EF Core was implementing and returning its own async interface, but the .Net Core infrastructure was unaware of it, thus was unable to use it on behalf of you.

---

The only way to force the previous behavior without using `ToList()` / `ToArray()` and similar is to hide the underlying source (hence the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`).

For `IEnumerable<T>` it's quite easy. All you need is to create custom extension method which uses C# iterator, e.g:

```
public static partial class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

and then use

```
return Ok(_carsDataModelContext.Cars.ToEnumerable());
```

If you want to return `IQueryable<T>`, the things get harder. Creating custom `IQueryable<T>` wrapper is not enough, you have to create custom `IQueryProvider` wrapper to make sure composing over returned wrapped `IQueryable<T>` would continue returning wrappers until the final `IEnumerator<T>` (or `IEnumerator`) is requested, and the returned underlying async enumerable is hidden with the aforementioned method.

Here is a simplified implementation of the above:

```
public static partial class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ToQueryable<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
        => new Queryable<T>(new QueryProvider(source.Provider), source.Expression);

    class Queryable<T> : IQueryable<T>
    {
        internal Queryable(IQueryProvider provider, Expression expression)
        {
            Provider = provider;
            Expression = expression;
        }
        public Type ElementType => typeof(T);
        public Expression Expression { get; }
        public IQueryProvider Provider { get; }
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<T>>(Expression)
            .ToEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }

    class QueryProvider : IQueryProvider
    {
        private readonly IQueryProvider source;
        internal QueryProvider(IQueryProvider source) => this.source = source;
        public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
        {
            var query = source.CreateQuery(expression);
            return (IQueryable)Activator.CreateInstance(
                typeof(Queryable<>).MakeGenericType(query.ElementType),
                this, query.Expression);
        }
        public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
            => new Queryable<TElement>(this, expression);
        public object Execute(Expression expression) => source.Execute(expression);
        public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression) => source.Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }
}
```

The query provider implementation is not fully correct, because it assumes that only the custom `Queryable<T>` will call `Execute` methods for creating `IEnumerable<T>`, and external calls will be used only for immediate methods like `Count`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Max` etc., but it should work for this scenario.

Other drawback of this implementation is that all EF Core specific `Queryable` extensions won't work, which might be an issue/showstopper if OData `$expand` relies on methods like `Include` / `ThenInclude`. But fixing that requires more complex implementation digging into EF Core internals.

With that being said, the usage of course would be:

```
return Ok(_carsDataModelContext.Cars.ToQueryable());
```