# Odata and IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, odata, asp.net-core-3.1, c#-8.0

Our application API uses odata and before upgrading to .net core 3.1 (we used .net core 2.2), the odata query was able to handle large data sets(for grid exports) with no issues. But as of 3.1, we hit the IAsyncEnumerable buffer limit of 8192. What is the best work around for the buffer limit, increasing the limit isn't possible because the user could be exporting any number of records that could exceed the buffer size.

I did notice that the odata response is chunked, so I tried to read the response stream using JavaScript but that also causes the buffer exception to occur.

Comment: IAsyncEnumerable itself doesn't buffer anything. Are you talking about `MvcOptions.MaxIAsyncEnumerableBufferLimit` ? This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986882/asyncenumerablereader-reached-the-configured-maximum-size-of-the-buffer-when-e).

Comment: In any case, humans and grids can't display more than 100 rows, much less 8192. Grids *don't* download all the data before display, they use data virtualization and paging, *especially* in HTML. Techniques like infinite scrolling can make this an invisible process. Most Javascript grids already support paging

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The grid does support paging and that's not the issue, the issue happens when the user tries to export the grid data to a csv file( they are exporting all pages).

Comment: That's not what you wrote though. What grid is it? If it supports paging, it should use the same paging mechanism to get the data. Could it be that the grid is configured for paging in the *UI* instead of data access? In any case, the (possible) duplicate explains the options - use paging, increase the buffer size, or not use IAsyncEnumerable.

Comment: In fact, instead of sending all the raw data to the grid for exporting, why not generate the CSV or Excel file on the server with eg CsvHelper or Epplus? This would be a lot faster and send a lot less data to the browser

Comment: How can I disable IAsyncEnumerable ? odata requires us to return IQueryable. We aren't  generating the csv on the server because the user might have filters applied to the grid prior to exporting. So we are utilizing odata filters to get all the pages for the export.

Comment: IQueryable doesn't mean you have to use IAsyncEnumerable. Which package are you using? The version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData that targets .NET Core 3.1 is still in beta and support for IAsyncEnumerable [isn't available yet](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1755)

Comment: What do your controllers, actions look like?

Comment: That what the controller is returning : 


`public override IQueryable<EntityListItem> Get()
        {
            return DbContext.Set<EntityListItem>().AsNoTracking();
        }`

Comment: That doesn't use IAsyncEnumerable and neither does Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData. Post the *full* exception text returned by Exception.ToString(). Don't return part of the message or describe the contents. The full text contains any inner exception and the call stack that led to the exception. This will show where the exception actually occurred

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem (OData / .Net Core 3.1 with Power BI Desktop as the client app).

Setting the page size on the controller method solved the problem for me :

```
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 100)]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok(AppDbContext.BiContracts.AsQueryable());
}
```