# IAsyncEnumerable and database queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, iasyncenumerable

I have three controller methods returning `IAsyncEnumerable` of `WeatherForecast`.
The first one #1 uses `SqlConnection` and yields results from an `async` reader.
The second one #2 uses EF Core with the ability to use `AsAsyncEnumerable` extension.
The third one #3 uses EF Core and `ToListAsync` method.

I think the downside of #1 and #2 is if I, for example, do something time-consuming inside while or for each then the database connection will be open till the end. In scenario #3 I'm able to iterate over the list with a closed connection and do something else.

But, I don't know if `IAsyncEnumerable` makes sense at all for database queries. Are there any memory and performance issues? If I use `IAsyncEnumerable` for returning let's say HTTP request from API, then once a response is returned it's not in memory and I'm able to return the next one and so on. But what about the database, where is the whole table if I select all rows (with `IAsyncEnumerable` or `ToListAsync`)?

Maybe it's not a question for StackOverflow and I'm missing something big here.

#1

```
[HttpGet("db", Name = "GetWeatherForecastAsyncEnumerableDatabase")]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetAsyncEnumerableDatabase()
{
    var connectionString = "";
    await using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table]";
    await using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

    connection.Open();
    await using var dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    while (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
    {
        yield return new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dataReader["Date"]),
            Summary = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Summary"]),
            TemperatureC = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["TemperatureC"])
        };
    }

    await connection.CloseAsync();
}
```

#2

```
[HttpGet("ef", Name = "GetWeatherForecastAsyncEnumerableEf")]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetAsyncEnumerableEf()
{
    await using var dbContext = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    await foreach (var item in dbContext
        .Tables
        .AsNoTracking()
        .AsAsyncEnumerable())
    {
        yield return new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = item.Date,
            Summary = item.Summary,
            TemperatureC = item.TemperatureC
        };
    }
}
```

#3

```
[HttpGet("eflist", Name = "GetWeatherForecastAsyncEnumerableEfList")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetAsyncEnumerableEfList()
{
    await using var dbContext = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    var result =  await dbContext
        .Tables
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Select(item => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = item.Date,
            Summary = item.Summary,
            TemperatureC = item.TemperatureC
        })
        .ToListAsync();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How many rows does the `[dbo].[Table]` have?

Comment: It might be 10000 up to 1000000

Comment: IAsyncEnumerable  has limit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986882/asyncenumerablereader-reached-the-configured-maximum-size-of-the-buffer-when-e

Comment: @foad-abdollahi good to know. It seems that it can be changed and also I'm using .NET 6 which support no buffering

Comment: Except from simple queries like `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table]`, is it possible to also have heavier queries that take considerable amount of time to complete? For example queries that execute a user defined function (or subquery) for each row in the `[dbo].[Table]`?

Comment: @theodor-zoulias Assume that the query is somehow optimized and returned in a satisfying time. Even for complicated queries. But might return a lot of data. So we don't need to expect a timeout issue.

Comment: What's your *actual* use case here? Returning an `IAsyncEnumerable` will send a JSON array to the caller, even if it writes the elements one by one. The *caller* will have to read and parse the entire payload. You'll avoid some blocking but that won't help the caller at all. To get *real* improvements you'd have to use a protocol that supports streaming like gRPC. Or you could use streaming JSON, ie emiting one JSON object per line. This would allow the caller to process the response line-by-line.

Comment: You can create a service that supports both gRPC and streaming JSON through [JSON transcoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/json-transcoding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (ie converting gRPC results to JSON) in ASP.NET Core 7.

Comment: Another option is to use SignalR and [stream results to the client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-6.0). In all cases the server sends a stream of objects to the client, which can process them as they arrive. SignalR works with every client. To use gRPC with web browsers you need gRPC-Web, which isn't quite as efficient as the binary gRPC protocol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Server-Side**

If I only cared with the server I'd go with option 4 in .NET 6 :

- Use an injected DbContext, write a LINQ query and return the results as `AsAsyncEnumerable()` instead of `ToListAsync()`

```
public class WeatherForecastsController:ControllerBase
{
    WeatherDbContext _dbContext;
    public WeatherForecastsController(WeatherDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext=dbContext;
    }

    public async IAsyncEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetAsync()
    {
        return _dbContext.Forecasts.AsNoTracking()
                         .Select(item => new WeatherForecast
                         {
                             Date = item.Date,
                             Summary = item.Summary,
                             TemperatureC = item.TemperatureC
                         })
                         .AsAsyncEnumerable();
    }
}
```

A new Controller instance is created for every request which mean the DbContext will be around for as long as the request is being processed.

The `[FromServices]` attribute can be used to inject a DbContext into the action method directly. The behavior doesn't really change, the DbContext is still scoped to the request :

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetAsync([FromServices] WeatherContext dbContext)
{
    ...
}
```

ASP.NET Core will emit a JSON array but at least the elements will be sent to the caller as soon as they're available.

**Client-Side**

The *client* will still have to receive the entire JSON array before deserialization.

One way to handle this in .NET 6 is to use [DeserializeAsyncEnumerable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasyncenumerable?view=net-6.0) to parse the response stream and emit items as they come:

```
using var stream=await client.GetAsStreamAsync(...);
var forecasts= JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable(stream, new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            DefaultBufferSize = 128
        });
await foreach(var forecast in forecasts)
{
...
}
```

The default buffer size is 16KB so a smaller one is needed if we want to receive objects as soon as possible.

This is a parser-specific solution though.

**Use a streaming JSON response**

A common workaround to this problem is to use streaming JSON aka JSON per line, aka Newline Delimited JSON aka JSON-NL or whatever. All names refer to the same thing - sending a stream of unindented JSON objects separated by a newline. It's an old technique that many tried to hijack and present as their own

```
{ "Date": "2022-10-18", Summary = "Blah", "TemperatureC"=18.5 }
{ "Date": "2022-10-18", Summary = "Blah", "TemperatureC"=18.5 }
{ "Date": "2022-10-18", Summary = "Blah", "TemperatureC"=18.5 }
```

That's not valid JSON but many parsers can handle it. Even if a parser can't, we can simply read one line of text at a time and parse it.

**Use a different protocol**

Even streaming JSON responses is a workaround. HTTP doesn't allow server-side streaming in the first place. The server has to send all data even if the client only reads the first 3 items since there's no way to cancel the response.

It's more efficient to use a protocol that *does* allow streaming. ASP.NET Core 6 offers two options:

- Use [ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0) with [Server-side streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-6.0#server-to-client-streaming) to push data to clients over WebSockets
- A [gRPC Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/services?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that uses [server-side streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/services?view=aspnetcore-6.0#server-streaming-method)

In both cases the server sends objects to clients as soon as they're available. Clients can cancel the stream as needed.

In a SignalR hub, the code could return an `IAsyncEnumerable` or a Channel:

```
public class AsyncEnumerableHub : Hub
{
    ...
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetForecasts()
    {
        return _dbContext.Forecasts.AsNoTracking()
                         .Select(item => new WeatherForecast
                         {
                             Date = item.Date,
                             Summary = item.Summary,
                             TemperatureC = item.TemperatureC
                         })
                         .AsAsyncEnumerable();
    }
}
```

In gRPC, the server method writes objects to a response stream :

```
public override async Task StreamingFromServer(ForecastRequest request,
    IServerStreamWriter<ForecastResponse> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
{
    ...
    await foreach (var item in queryResults)
    {
        if (context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }
        await responseStream.WriteAsync(new ForecastResponse{Forecast=item});
    }
}
```

Comment: ```The server has to send all data even if the client only reads the first 3 items since there's no way to cancel the response.``` - The client can always send tcp fin and the connection will be terminated. Http doesnt have to implement it if the layer below already does.

Comment: @JKamsker that's closes the connection, it doesn't cancel the request. Cancelling means that the *server* is somehow instructed to stop processing the request, generating and sending new results. Closing the TCP connection isn't provided by HTTP libraries because it's not that simple. First, OSs use connection pooling to *avoid* closing and reopening connections. Second, an HTTP request passes proxies, caches and load balancers before it reaches the web server. The web server may take a while to realize the client disappeared. Finally, crashing server code is a *very* costly way of cancelling

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you explain to me, what is the difference between my #2 and your #4 case? Because they both use IAsyncEnumerable. I'm just using await for each because of my mapping. But the behavior is the same, right? Elements will be sent to the caller as soon as they're available. Tried with blazor.