# ASP.NET rest api response in chunks

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I have a rest API that takes longer to populate complete result data (as it iterates the remove directory recursively which is time taking sometimes) during that time the client is keep waiting. once all the data is populated we are sending a response back to the client.

The problem with the above method is the client is keep waiting until all the data is populated.

is there a way in .net, the Rest API sends the data back to the client in chunks as the data keeps on populating? (without client to wait till whole data is generated).

Can you provide a sample of how to achieve the above requirement in .Net ?

Comment: It's a bit broad to be answered accurately, but there are at least 2 ways to achieve that : First is not sending the whole data, but paginate it (the first N results or the results X to X + N). Second is to do asynchronous calls to avoid the client to hang

Comment: Are you looking for [the `PushStreamContent` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh995285(v=vs.118))? [Stephen Cleary wrote about it back in 2016](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/10/async-pushstreamcontent.html).

Comment: I may be wrong but isn't IAsyncEnumerable used for this kind of thing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876817/clarification-on-how-iasyncenumerable-works-with-asp-net-web-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clarification on how IAsyncEnumerable works with ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876817/clarification-on-how-iasyncenumerable-works-with-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 1):

It depends how long client should wait.

For long operations maybe it better to create more endpoints:

1. endpoint to start operation, returns operation id
2. endpoint for cheking operation status for given id
   returns response:

   - operation status: completed, in-progress
   - jobs (chunks), chunk:id1 - completed, chunk:id2 - in-progress
3. endpoint for retrieving jobs (chunks) results - for given operation id and chunk id

Comment: I am new to asp.net any sample code can you please point to?

Comment: just create 3 endpoints: api/v1/operations/start, api/v1/operations/status, api/v1/operations/getchunk. If you dont understand how REST Api works, you need to start from some tutorial...