# Asp.Net Core API Controller method returning IAsyncEnumerable<T> not producing the intended behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, iasyncenumerable

I have an API Controller setup which return 277,000+ items:

```
[HttpPost]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<LocationDto> GetLocations([FromBody] LocationReportQueryDto locationReportQuery, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var result = await locationReportDataAccess.GetFilteredLocationsAsync(locationReportQuery, token);

    foreach (var location in result)
    {
        yield return location;
    }
}
```

and instead of streaming each location back, Asp.Net is actually buffering the response.

Client side code:

```
public async Task<List<ItemLocDto>> GetFilteredLocationsAsync(LocationReportQueryDto locationReportQuery, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("DataAccess");
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/reports/LocationReport/GetFilteredLocations", locationReportQuery, token);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var list = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<ItemLocDto>>(cancellationToken: token);
    if (list == null) throw new HttpRequestException("LocationReportDataAccess GetFilteredLocationsAsync HTTP Call - Response is null");
    return list;
}
```

I'm getting this exception upon returning from this method:

```
blazor.server.js:1 [2022-12-18T04:51:19.544Z] Error: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LimitMemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ChunkedEncodingReadStream.CopyToAsyncCore(Stream destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent.SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Portal.Infrastructure.DataAccess.Reports.LocationReportDataAccess.GetFilteredLocationsAsync(LocationReportQueryDto locationReportQuery, CancellationToken token) in C:\Users\LOFT\RiderProjects\Portal\src\Libraries\Portal.Infrastructure\DataAccess\Reports\LocationReportDataAccess.cs:line 30
   at Portal.Services.Reporting.LocationResultsService.GetResultsAsync(LocationInputConfig config, CancellationToken token) in C:\Users\LOFT\RiderProjects\Portal\src\Libraries\Portal.Services\Reporting\LocationResultsService.cs:line 137
   at Portal.Web.Pages.Reports.LocationList.OnGenerateClick() in C:\Users\LOFT\RiderProjects\Portal\src\Presentation\Portal.Web\Pages\Reports\LocationList.razor:line 679
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

I cannot use pagination because I'm using a legacy database, so I'm trying to stream all of the data from the API endpoint.

The "result" is of type List<LocationDto,> could this be the problem, or do I need to reduce a buffer size somewhere?

Comment: "_I cannot use pagination because I'm using a legacy database._" What does the one thing have to do with the other? You can do pagination with any database, even a flat file. You may have to write more of your own code with some dbs than others, but it can always be done. Returning 227,000 items sounds like a sure-fire way of getting an `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: You make a good point about pagination. I'm producing the report on the client side, so I need all of the data in order to produce that report. It's not always the case of 277,000 row, but it can be with large reports. Do you think pagination would be a better approach?

Comment: Even if I'm not doing it the right way, I still want to understand why this controller method isn't streaming the results back, isn't that the intended purpose of IAsyncEnumerable as a return type?

Comment: What type is `result`? If you manifest the enumeration at any point in transit, it will try to put it all into memory.

Comment: Oh wait, is the exception thrown at client or server?

Comment: You can see fro the exception, the problem is that the client is buffering the entire response with a memory stream. Can you show the client code?

Comment: Where is the line that throw this exception? Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877652/3744182) by tymtam to [Clarification on how IAsyncEnumerable works with ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58876817/3744182), in .NET 6 (but not earlier) `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` should be streamed -- but will not be in earlier versions.  If using .NET 6 or later, what version are you using?  What happens if you do an `await Task.Delay(1);` every 100 locations?

Comment: @fildor The result is of type List<LocationDto> and the exception is thrown server side, right after the foreach loop.

Comment: @vernou I added the rest of the stack trace. Line 30 from the stack trace, on client side is the second line: 
var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/reports/LocationReport/GetFilteredLocations", locationReportQuery, token);

Comment: @dbc I'm targeting .NET  6.0.200 and if I include "await Task.Delay(1)" in the loop, it will iterate over each result item, and while debugging both server and client, the client doesn't receive any data during each iteration.

Comment: I think pagination should be the best option. so many items is neither friendly to your application nor to your users I think ..

Answer (score 1):

Your exception stack trace shows that you're getting the OOM from within `GetFilteredLocationsAsync`. This is because it returns a `List<ItemLocDto>`, presumably reading the entire response into memory as JSON and then parsing them into `ItemLocDto` objects while building/extending a `List<T>` to contain those objects. It's the `GetFilteredLocationsAsync` that is buffering into memory.

So, you'll need to change something about how `/reports/LocationReport/GetFilteredLocations` is called. If it can stream results, then you may be able to stream from the source to `GetLocations` without buffering in-memory as a `List<T>`. Otherwise, you'll probably need some sort of pagination on both APIs.